# Citation warning errors using Overleaf

Tags: citing, natbib, overleaf, warnings

I´ve been using Overleaf for a while to write my master thesis. It has never given me any problem until yesterday. The document compiled perfectly, with all the citations and the bibliography printed. However, I let it open online the whole night, and the day after 99 warnings appeared regarding, because apparently all the citations were wrong with the following message:

[image]

Yesterday I create a new version of the document and copy the main text to the old one, and I don´t know why but it works and all the warnings disappeared.

However, today I let the overleaf page open again, and now I encounter the same problem as yesterday. I can re-copy all again, but I do not if someone knows what is happening, why and how to fix it more efficiently.

I also used a minimal working example to see if there is any issue, and it is not (here is the code, for instance).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=2.9cm, right=2.9cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=violet, linkcolor=Blue, citecolor=Sepia}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xfrac}


\begin{document}



\chapter{Introducción y justificación}
\label{ch:Intr}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\chapter{Objetivos y plan de trabajo}
\label{ch:Contex}
\citep{bransford1990teaching}


\chapter{Revisión bibliográfica y contenidos curriculares}
\label{ch:Capítulo 3}



\appendix
\chapter{Apéndices}
\label{ch:apéndice}

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Referencias}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía}


\end{document}
```

And the two last references I added to the Referencias.bib

```
@article{bransford1990teaching,
  title={Teaching thinking and content knowledge: Toward an integrated approach},
  author={Bransford, John D and Vye, Nancy and Kinzer, Charles and Risko, Victoria},
  journal={Dimensions of thinking and cognitive instruction},
  volume={1},
  pages={381--413},
  year={1990}
}

@article{lyons2006puzzle,
  title={The puzzle of falling enrolments in physics and chemistry courses: Putting some pieces together},
  author={Lyons, Terry},
  journal={Research in science education},
  volume={36},
  number={3},
  pages={285--311},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

Comment: Hello there! Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. I don't know what could cause this. But you can reach me on Overleaf support email address and we can see what's going on there. If you include the project's URL, it will help us help you faster. Then if it's something worth sharing with others, I will make an answer here.

Comment: I´ve just sent to the Overleaf support email. I download the Overleaf project in a .zip foulder, and the document and references are perfect when using TeXmaker. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the Overleaf support team, the problem has been fixed, so I´m going to put it here if someone encounters the same problem in the future.

They told me that this was a strange error because sometimes the build tool does not detect that the bibliography generation needs to run.

However, the solution was straightforward by adding the comman  `\typeout{}` before the
`\bibliography{...}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think its missing `\usepackage{cite}`. use it in the preamble, you'll get it

Comment: The `cite` package is generally not needed for `\cite` to work. Here it is not needed at all, since the OP actually loads `natbib`. (`natbib` and `cite` should not be used together. `natbib` implements almost all of `cite`'s features, so there is no reason to load both packages.)